# How to get parameters of another build?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I use parameterized builds in a lot of places. I'd like a pipeline's input to be a build number of a different job. I haven't found a clean way to query Jenkins from within groovy to get the other job's build parameters. Does anybody have a snippet to share?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me in script console

```java
import hudson.model.ParametersAction

def getParams(String project, String buildNumber){

  def params=[]

  Jenkins.instance.getItem(project).getBuild(buildNumber).getActions(ParametersAction)
  .each { action ->
    action.getParameters().each {
      params << it
    }
  }

  return params
}
```

Comment: `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod jenkins.model.Jenkins getInstance` and in the approval console it specifically said "Approving this signature may introduce a security vulnerability! You are advised to deny it."

Comment: I had to switch out `getItem()` with `getItemByFullName()` because it's in a folder. Otherwise, it worked, thanks! I'm going to leave the question open until next week to see if there's any better (non-security-warning) answers.

Comment: I don't expect that you can access this information without hitting script security.