# How to trigger a replay of another build from another job programmatically

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I trigger a replay of a build from another job?

Context of Problem: I want to be able to have a job that can prioritize a build over others for another job (that has concurrency disabled). I was thinking I could do this by killing / cancelling jobs in the queue, triggering the new job, and then replay the ones that were cancelled.

I think I know how to cancel the jobs in the queue. I.e. by something like:

```
def buildNumbers = []

    def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(TARGET_JOB)
    def builds = job.builds
    job = null
    for (build in builds) {
        if (build.isBuilding() && !(build.isInProgress())) {
            if(build instanceof WorkflowRun) {
                WorkflowRun run = (WorkflowRun) build
                if(!dryRun) {
                    //hard kill
                    run.doKill()
                    //release pipeline concurrency locks
                    StageStepExecution.exit(run)
                }
                println "Killed ${run}"
                buildNumbers.add(build.getNumber())
            } else if(build instanceof FreeStyleBuild) {
                FreeStyleBuild run = (FreeStyleBuild) build
                if(!dryRun) {
                    run.executor.interrupt(Result.ABORTED)
                }
                println "Killed ${run}"
            } else {
                println "WARNING: Don't know how to handle ${item.class}"
            }
        }
    }
```

But say I have saved these builds or build numbers that were killed, how can I replay them?
I am open to other alternatives as well that solves this problem of prioritizing one build ahead of another.

Comment: If as you say your project has concurrency disabled, would you just re-insert the build into the queue (standard build scheduling with the same parameters) ?

Comment: @PatriceM., yes that would work. How can I obtain the properties? I don't see a java method or property here for obtianing the build/run properties: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Run.java

Comment: Sorry, meant to say "parameters" instead of "properties".
How can I obtain the parameters of a Run ( https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Run.java ) ?

Comment: Looks like this is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44827422/6674271

Comment: Yes, I believe this is the answer to your question indeed. The other part concerns triggering (scheduling) builds via the Jenkins api : https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractProject.html#scheduleBuild2(int,hudson.model.Cause,hudson.model.Action...) . You need to pass parameter values as a collection ParameterAction object, e.g. 'new ParametersAction(new StringParameterValue("PARAM1", "value"))'